# What is the meaning of the 2nd parameter of double.tryparse method in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a question about the `TryParse` method in VB.

```
double.tryparse(string, 0)
```

What is the meaning of the 0?
I look up the Microsoft documentation but can't understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be the VB.NET equivalent to `_` acting as a [discard token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards).

In the case of your example, it seems likely that the result of the conversion at this point is of no consequence: it only matters that it *can be* converted.

As such, you could use it like this:

```
If double.TryParse(input, 0) Then
    ' do something
Else
    ' complain loudly
End If
```

[Rextester example](https://rextester.com/REOT75436)

Since 0 only works for types compatible with conversions from `Integer`, it's probably better to use `Nothing` (as suggested by [@Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) in the comments):

```
If double.TryParse(input, Nothing) Then
    ' do something
Else
    ' complain loudly
End If
```

Comment: You can just use `Nothing` as the discard: `If Integer.TryParse(intString, Nothing)`, `If Date.TryParse(dateString, Nothing)` etc. (so you don't worry about the Type)

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is where the result goes. It's weird to see a `0` (or any constant!) there. It should be a variable:

```
Dim input As String = ...
Dim result As Double
If double.TryParse(input, result) Then
   ' result now has input's numeric value
End If
```